# Issue with organizing a large project with .c and .h files

Tags: c, makefile, organization, project-organization

So I have quite a lot of .c and .h files in my project:

Here are just the headers of the files that are having an issue:

```
#ifndef OUTPUTUTILITIES_H 
#define OUTPUTUTILITIES_H 
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "parser.h" // <== IF I REMOVE THIS include everything works. But I need to include this here
#endif

#ifndef PARSER_H 
#define PARSER_H 
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "utilities.h"
#endif

#ifndef UTILITIES_H 
#define UTILITIES_H
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "variableVector.h"
#endif

#ifndef VARIABLEVECTOR_H
#define VARIABLEVECTOR_H
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#endif
```

Can someone please explain why I cannot #include "parser.h" file in my outputUtilites.h file? And also what are the general principles behind organizing your import .h files?

I also wanted to let you know that in the corresponding .c file I only include the corresponding .h file and nothing else. For example in my parser.c file I ONLY include parser.h and in my ouputUtilities.c file I ONLY include outputUtilities.h file.

Comment: What kind of error do you get? What's your content of parser.h? Without those information, no one could guess it out.

Comment: You have an import cycle somewhere. Figure out where and fix it.